# In R, do we have to select every continuous variable by hands when running Correlation test?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataset with 100 variables, 70 continuous variables, and 30 categorical variables. All of the variables are of the class integer.

If I wish to run a `Pearson/Spearman Correlation` on the continuous variables, do I have to type each of the continuous variables by hand? Or is there a way to run them by batch. Thanks

Comment: `sapply(somedat, function(x) is.numeric(x) & !is.integer(x))` returns a logical vector indicating which columns are floating-point and not integer. With that, you can typically automate work on the `data.frame`.

Comment: `!sapply(somedat, is.factor)` might also be useful

Comment: Thanks. But both types are integers. For example: age (30 , 32,... ) int   sex (1,2,1,...) int .

Comment: This is kinda two questions: how to determine which columns to iterate over, and how to iterate over all possible combinations. I think I suggested ways to look for the first, and the second can be done using `combn` and `apply`. Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Yes, lol. I made a subset of all continuous variables by hand. I can do this with small numbers of variables but when it comes to 1000 variables, I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: `which(sapply(df, is.numeric))` will return you the column number of numeric variable. Is that what you want?

Comment: I wish to find a way to distinguish between continuous and categorical variables without doing it manually.

Comment: I would assume that your continuous variables have far more unique values than the categorical values. Maybe you can determine a threshold to distinguish the two classes.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. perhaps more than 10 distinct values. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have logic to separate two types of variables logically, you would be able to code R to do it.

Let's use `mtcars` data as an example. Althougy all the variables of `mtcars` are numeric, the idea should be the same. Let's first convert all variables with less than 10 values to `factor`. Then, we can easily pick variables `is.numeric` for your analysis.

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(mtcars, function(x) if(length(table(x)) < 10) 
                          as.factor(x) else x))
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(mtcars, function(x) 
                       if(length(levels(as.factor(x))) < 10) as.factor(x) else x))
```

Then,

```
my_numeric <- Filter(is.numeric, df)
cor(my_numeric)

            mpg       disp         hp        drat         wt        qsec
mpg   1.0000000 -0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.68117191 -0.8676594  0.41868403
disp -0.8475514  1.0000000  0.7909486 -0.71021393  0.8879799 -0.43369788
hp   -0.7761684  0.7909486  1.0000000 -0.44875912  0.6587479 -0.70822339
drat  0.6811719 -0.7102139 -0.4487591  1.00000000 -0.7124406  0.09120476
wt   -0.8676594  0.8879799  0.6587479 -0.71244065  1.0000000 -0.17471588
qsec  0.4186840 -0.4336979 -0.7082234  0.09120476 -0.1747159  1.00000000
```

The following variables have been excluded from above analysis as they have less than 10 categories:

```
my_factor <- Filter(is.factor, df)

head(my_factor)

  cyl vs am gear carb
1   6  0  1    4    4
2   6  0  1    4    4
3   4  1  1    4    1
4   6  1  0    3    1
5   8  0  0    3    2
6   6  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks seems twofold: one related to subsetting and one related to how to run correlation tests on bunches of columns in one go. So this answer comes in two parts.

**Part 1**:

Applying the logic mentioned in my comment--that a distinction between the continuous and the categorical variables could be made by assuming that the former have far more, and the latter far fewer, distinct values and that hence a threshold value could be determined to distinguish them--you could proceed thus:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = sample(1:2, 100, replace = T),
  v2 = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T),
  v3 = sample(1:30, 100, replace = T),
  v4 = sample(1:50, 100, replace = T),
  v5 = sample(1:40, 100, replace = T),
  v6 = sample(1:60, 100, replace = T)
)
```

Assuming that `10` is a sensible threshold value, to subset the dataframe on those (presumably continuous) columns that have more than 10 `unique` values, you can use `sapply` in this way:

```
df_cont <- df[, sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 10)]
```

To check, run `head`:

```
head(df_cont)
  v3 v4 v5 v6
1  8 40 40 22
2 29  1  6 22
3 19 39 37 18
4 16 37 24  5
5 13 32 16 22
6 27 25 18 11
```

**Part 2:**

First make a dummy dataframe with all possible combinations of columns using `expand.grid`:

```
combinations <- expand.grid(colnames(df), colnames(df))
```

Then `apply` the `cor.test` to all combinations:

```
apply(combinations, 1, function(i){
  x <- df_cont[,i[[1]]]
  y <- df_cont[,i[[2]]]
  cor.test(x, y, method = "kendall")
})
```